# iOS twitter integration. User not found

Tags: ios, twitter

When I am using the tweet share sheet on latest iOS for iPhone and iPad and I @someone it starts to prefetch matching names but certain names never show up. Any ideas what makes some show and some not?

Comment: I *think* this has to do with most recently seen people.

Comment: that wouldn't make sense because some of the people that show up hardly ever tweet and the ones that don't show up are very prolific tweeters